# Remove Stopwords in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, stop-words

I'm developing an algorithm to remove stopword.
I am transforming a txt file into a list and thus passing in the algorithm for removal.

**Example of file lines:**

```
'mora vai nascer viver cair falar','positivo'
'deixa ver entendi vai crescer vai passar ve','positivo'
'so deveria ter foi agradeco de passei passei fez','positivo'
'nunca nao nao muito nao mais','negativo'
'a nao ate infelizmente ai ate quando','negativo'
'nao perto nao quanto menos nao sim nao nem simplesmente','negativo'
```

**Code**

```
with open('BasePalavras.txt') as arquivo:
     baseTeste = [linha.strip() for linha in arquivo]


stopwords = ['a', 'agora', 'algum', 'alguma', 'aquele', 'aqueles', 'de', 'deu', 'do', 'e', 'estou', 'esta', 'esta',
         'ir', 'meu', 'muito', 'mesmo', 'no', 'nossa', 'o', 'outro', 'para', 'que', 'sem', 'talvez', 'tem', 'tendo',
         'tenha', 'teve', 'tive', 'todo', 'um', 'uma', 'umas', 'uns', 'vou']

def removestopword(texto):
     frases=[]
     for(palavras, emocao) in texto:
         semstopwords = [p for p in palavras.splits() if p not in stopwords]
         frases.append((semstopwords, emocao))
return frases

print (removestopword(baseTeste))
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/Rivaldo/PycharmProjects/Mineracao/Principal.py", line 22, in <module>
          print (removestopword(baseTeste))
     File "C:/Users/Rivaldo/PycharmProjects/Mineracao/Principal.py", line 17, in removestopword
          for(palavras, emocao) in texto:
   ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: The error is very clear `for (palavras, emocao) in texto:` there are more than 2 values to unpack. What are hoping for in `emocao`? Can you provide some example lines of data from the file?

Comment: Did you, by any chance mean `linha.strip().split(',')` or `linha.split(',')` instead of just `linha.strip()`? All `.strip()` will do is to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: the idea of split (), is the breaking of lines. @talkdirty

Comment: @RivaldoHater no, the idea of `.split()` is to group an iterable into sections using a denominator you supply to it. The default denominator of split is the line break, but by manually specifying the denominator like `.split(',')` it can also break lines into smaller pieces. As an aside, please use english variable names when posting to SO in the future. Makes the code a lot easier to read people that don't know your language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('BasePalavras.txt') as arquivo:
    baseTeste = [linha.strip().split(',') for linha in arquivo]


stopwords = ['a', 'agora', 'algum', 'alguma', 'aquele', 'aqueles', 'de', 'deu', 'do', 'e', 'estou', 'esta', 'esta',
         'ir', 'meu', 'muito', 'mesmo', 'no', 'nossa', 'o', 'outro', 'para', 'que', 'sem', 'talvez', 'tem', 'tendo',
         'tenha', 'teve', 'tive', 'todo', 'um', 'uma', 'umas', 'uns', 'vou']

def removestopword(texto):
    frases=[]
    for (palavras, emocao) in texto:
        semstopwords = [p for p in palavras.split() if p not in stopwords]
        frases.append((semstopwords, emocao))
    return frases

print (removestopword(baseTeste))
```

Changed `baseTeste = [linha.strip() for linha in arquivo]` to `baseTeste = [linha.strip().split(',') for linha in arquivo]`

and

`semstopwords = [p for p in palavras.splits() if p not in stopwords]` to `semstopwords = [p for p in palavras.split() if p not in stopwords]`.

Comment: presented another error: 
**ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**

Comment: @RivaldoHater Is this error on this line: `for (palavras, emocao) in texto:`, If yes, then are you sure your input file contains lines in this format: `"something","another_thing"`  ?

Comment: yes, already tried to modify the structure of the text more presents the same error.

Comment: I had to put the sentences in this way:  ("something","another_thing")

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

```
stopwords = ['a', 'agora', 'algum', 'alguma', 'aquele', 'aqueles', 'de', 'deu', 'do', 'e', 'estou', 'esta', 'esta',
     'ir', 'meu', 'muito', 'mesmo', 'no', 'nossa', 'o', 'outro', 'para', 'que', 'sem', 'talvez', 'tem', 'tendo',
     'tenha', 'teve', 'tive', 'todo', 'um', 'uma', 'umas', 'uns', 'vou']

def remove_stopwords(text):
    phrases = []
    for (sentence, _) in text:
        sentence_without_stopwords = [word for word in sentence.split() if word not in stopwords]
        phrases.append(sentence_without_stopwords)
    return phrases

with open('input.txt') as raw_text:
    sentence_sentiments = []
    lines = [line for line in raw_text]
    for line in lines:
        sentence, sentiment = line.split(',')
        sentence_sentiments.append((sentence[1:-1], sentiment[1:-1]))
    print(remove_stopwords(sentence_sentiments))
```

Notice how, in your provided code, `baseTeste` is an array that contains a list of strings, representing the lines of your input file. This is not what you want, as you're attempting to loop (`for(palavras, emocao) in texto:`) over the `(sentence, sentiment)` pairs inside these lines. You are thus missing the middle step of splitting each line into `(sentence, sentiment)` pairs.